# How to have function returned value in a SML record

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am new to SML, trying to explore SML record and types, specifically how to have function inside a record.

For example, I created below type-

```
type foo={
    var1:int,
    f1: int -> int    // want to have result of function f1 here
 };
```

Now if I declare record of type 'foo'-

```
val rec1 = { var1= 10, ....}
```

I am not getting how to populate the 2nd parameter in the record. f1(10) is giving error.Also, can we declare and define the function inside 'type' like below -

```
type foo ={
    var1:int,
    f1 (x)=x+x
 };
```

Please share your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a function expression:

```
val r = {var1 = 10, f = fn x => x}
```

No, you cannot define the value of a record field in a type definition. But you can define a little helper function as a "constructor":

```
fun new_foo i = {var1 = i, f = fn x => x+x}
```

Comment: Thanks.I did this- - 

val footest:foo={var1 = 1,f1 = fn x=> x+x};
- #var1 footest;
val it = 1 : int - 
-(#f1 footest) 1;
val it = 2 : int

But if I want to pass var1 as argument to function x, it is not working.
- #f1 (#var1 footest);
stdIn:202.1-202.20 Error: operator and operand do not agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {f1:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int

Comment: Well, that would be `(#f1 footest) (#var1 footest)`.